# Is it possible to change the title colour of the Pie chart using Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

Is there any way to change the title colour of the Pie Chart using Google Charts APIS?

Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 7):

Set the `titleTextStyle.color` option (it accepts an HTML color string):

```
titleTextStyle: {
    color: '#a34f8b'
}
```